Band structure using NEGF method in Transiesta
I have used transiesta to calculate electronic transmission functions using NEGF approach. Is there any way to calculate the band structure of the central scattering region in transiesta supercell? So, that we can see the band structure under different voltage bias.
Thanks

The NEGF approach does not have any periodicities along the semi-infinite directions. As is defined by the semi-infinite part of the electrodes.
Therefore one cannot create a band-structure along the semi-infinite directions.
What one can do is to calculate the density of states for the transverse k-points, thus getting a band-structure where all of the states along the semi-infinite direction is folded into the $\Gamma$ point.
However, I am not sure that will give you what you want.
So, essentially no, the only way to know about states, is through the density of states, which can be calculated in a $k$-resolved quantity, thus giving hints at how different $k$'s has different states.
